# Wordpress - Only show pages that have children

Tags: wordpress, list, parent

i need to display all parent pages with their child pages in a Wordpress theme's sidebar.
The catch is, i only want to display parent pages that have child pages.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did neither of those answers work?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll probably have to do is call all of the pages, check each one for children, and then only display the page names if children are present.

```
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);?>
if( count( $children ) != 0 ) { // Has Children }
<li>Page Title</li>
else { // No children }
```

It's a little cumbersome, but WP doesn't have any built-in method for doing it otherwise.

Comment: What i need is an automated way of displaying those pages, since the client will be able to add pages himself.

Comment: This should work for that. You put the code in your side bar template to run a query that searches for all pages, and then set up a `while` loop that uses the code above to check the resulting pages for children and generate your list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. However I do not know if there is an actual widget to accomplish this. You have 3 options:

- see if you can find a widget to do this (I don't think there is one),
  or,
- write a widget yourself, or,
- install a widget that allows you to execute PHP (they do exists) and write a script to do it.

Comment: Thanks mate, but i try not to use any plugins or widgets for this.

Comment: You are welcome, personally I feel the same, however, I try not to alter the core WP files as they will be over written on any updates, which is I go with the third option.